# Merge two data frames with non unique identifier

Tags: r, merge

Trying to merge two data frames in R:
One looks like:

```
Id
1
2
3
4
```

Another looks like:

```
Id Name
 1  A
 1  B
 2  B
 3  C
 3  A
```

Expecting result:

```
ID A B C 
1  1 1 0 
2  0 1 0
3  1 0 1
```

I have no idea how to merge data frame in this way. Any thought?

Comment: why do you need 1st table? You can do `table(df2)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. since table 1 has much more information that Id and I would like to keep those and add other information from table 2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(Id = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(Id = c(1,1,2,3,3), Name = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  spread(Name, value, fill = 0) %>% 
  inner_join(df1, by = "Id")

  Id A B C
1  1 1 1 0
2  2 0 1 0
3  3 1 0 1
```